# ON statement in sql for joins

Tags: mysql

Good day! I'm searching the entire web for the purpose of 'on' statement in MySQL. But i can't find an exact answer about the purpose of it. For example:

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderID
FROM Customers
INNER JOIN Orders
ON Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID
ORDER BY Customers.CustomerName;
```

What i'm trying to trace is to find the purpose of this:

```
ON Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not look for the `ON` syntax but for the `inner join` syntax and there you will find a lot explanations on line. E.g. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

The **'`ON`'**  in this case is similar to `'Where'` It defines on which fields the join is based.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are fooled by the fact that *in your particular case*, the joining field name is the same in both table: `CustomerID`.

That is not always the case, hence the necessity of specifying in SQL which fields are used for joining tables, in the `ON`clause.

Answer (score 0):

You are joining two tables on customerId.

It means that you will join two tables side by side having same customerId from both the tables, so you could select customer and their order together at the same time.